# Jupyter returns empty cell when executing SQL with jupysql

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, duckdb

I used SQL in Jupyter with jupysql magics %sql and %%sql. It worked fine until it didn't. Now when I execute SQL it does not print out the result in the output cell. I suspect conflicts with any recently installed python libraries.

Here is a snippet:

```
import duckdb as db

%load_ext sql

%config SqlMagic.autopandas = True

%sql duckdb:///:memory:
```

```
%sql select * from 'data.csv'
```

Output:

```
 * duckdb:///:memory:
Done.
```

I realised that by setting `%config SqlMagic.autopandas = False` the output will display the header but no rows.
I reinstalled jupysql, notebook, ipython but it did not solve it.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything in the file you're querying?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same when having a semicolon at the end of my query.
Since a recent version of jupysql.

Which versions of pandas, duckdb and jupysql are you using?
Could you paste the result of `pip freeze` ?

I tried with these versions:

```
    appnope==0.1.3
    asttokens==2.4.0
    backcall==0.2.0
    backoff==2.2.1
    certifi==2023.7.22
    charset-normalizer==3.3.0
    click==8.1.7
    comm==0.1.4
    debugpy==1.8.0
    decorator==5.1.1
    duckdb==0.9.1
    duckdb-engine==0.9.2
    executing==2.0.0
    idna==3.4
    ipykernel==6.25.2
    ipython==8.16.1
    ipython-genutils==0.2.0
    jedi==0.19.1
    Jinja2==3.1.2
    jupysql==0.10.2
    jupysql-plugin==0.2.5
    jupyter_client==8.4.0
    jupyter_core==5.4.0
    MarkupSafe==2.1.3
    matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
    monotonic==1.6
    nest-asyncio==1.5.8
    numpy==1.26.1
    packaging==23.2
    pandas==1.5.3
    parso==0.8.3
    pexpect==4.8.0
    pickleshare==0.7.5
    platformdirs==3.11.0
    ploomber-core==0.2.14
    posthog==3.0.2
    prettytable==3.9.0
    prompt-toolkit==3.0.39
    psutil==5.9.6
    ptyprocess==0.7.0
    pure-eval==0.2.2
    Pygments==2.16.1
    python-dateutil==2.8.2
    pytz==2023.3.post1
    PyYAML==6.0.1
    pyzmq==25.1.1
    requests==2.31.0
    six==1.16.0
    SQLAlchemy==2.0.22
    sqlglot==18.15.0
    sqlparse==0.4.4
    stack-data==0.6.3
    tornado==6.3.3
    traitlets==5.11.2
    typing_extensions==4.8.0
    tzdata==2023.3
    urllib3==2.0.7
    wcwidth==0.2.8
```

I tried to reproduce it (since I saw the same issue in the recent past) but I did not succeed.

I realise this isn't an answer but I do not yet have commenting rights.

Comment: Hi, don't forget to convert this into a *comment* when you get commenting rights.

Comment: thanks for your comment. here are the versions I have installed Pandas 2.1.1
DuckDB 0.9.0
JupySQL 0.1.7

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it. But I doubt that you use version 0.1.7 of jupysql.
Trying to install that version fails here:

pip install "jupysql==0.1.7"

=> ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupysql==0.1.7

Comment: Could you paste the output of pip freeze ?

Comment: 0.1.7 is probably your version of jupysql-plugin, but even with that version I cannot reproduce it.